# how to filter a table use lambdaj or other tools

Tags: java, collections, filter, guava, lambdaj

How can I filter a table using [lambdaj](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/)?

Given the following table:

```
id  name   age  male  salary
1   tom    22    y      3k
2   nancy  24    n      3.5k
3   jack   22    y      2k
4   jmme   29    y      4k
```

If I applied the filter:

```
age >= 22 && salary > 3k
```

then I would get:

```
2   nancy  24    n      3.5k
4   jmme   29    y      4k
```

As you know, I cannot create a domain class for it, which prevents me from using the following syntax:

```
filter(having(on(Person.class).getAge(),greaterThan(22)), myManList);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   
/**
         * 
         *  序号   年份 地区      GDP
         *  1       2011    北京      1233
         *  2       2010    天津      2412
         *  3       2012    上海      1939
         *  4       2009    深圳      1389
         *  5       2013    重庆      1492
         * */
         Table aTable = HashBasedTable.create();  
         aTable.put("1", "id", "1");
         aTable.put("1", "年份", "2011");
         aTable.put("1", "地区", "北京");
         aTable.put("1", "GDP", "1233");

         aTable.put("2", "id", "2");
         aTable.put("2", "年份", "2010");
         aTable.put("2", "地区", "天津");
         aTable.put("2", "GDP", "2412");

         aTable.put("3", "id", "3");
         aTable.put("3", "年份", "2012");
         aTable.put("3", "地区", "上海");
         aTable.put("3", "GDP", "1939");

         aTable.put("4", "id", "4");
         aTable.put("4", "年份", "2009");
         aTable.put("4", "地区", "深圳");
         aTable.put("4", "GDP", "1389");

         aTable.put("5", "id", "5");
         aTable.put("5", "年份", "2013");
         aTable.put("5", "地区", "重庆");
         aTable.put("5", "GDP", "1492");


         List>  li = filter(
                    having(on(Map.class).get("年份"),isIn(Arrays.asList("2009","2011")))
                    .and(having(on(Map.class).get("地区"),isIn(Arrays.asList("深圳"))))
                            ,aTable.rowMap().values());
         System.out.println(li);
```